# How to use wildcard in elastalert rules

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, elastalert, elasticsearch-watcher

I need help in ELASTALERT

I have a log message like this :

```
log.info("Server is started at "+LocalDateTime.now());
```

and I need to write a query in rule for it:
I am writing as

```
- query:
      query_string:
        query: "message: *Server is*"
```

It seems like its not working. Can anyone tell me how to do it?